# Override colorbox onClose

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using the following which works great. I am just wondering if it would be possible to override the onClosed after the box is loaded

```
    $.colorbox({href:"fff.html",
    onClosed:function(){ window.parent.location.reload(true); }
    });
```

I know that I can use the resize function after the box is loaded to resize the dimensions. Would it be possible to use the close functions similarly to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it exactly the way you are attempting

```
$.colorbox({href:"fff.html",
    onClosed:function(){ 
       //This is your method that triggers onClose
       // SO go ahead, override it 

       //You can also call multiple function on it like

       function1(); //call function 1
       function2(); //call function 2
    }
});
```

Or, you can pass a function name to the onClosed() too like

```
$.colorbox({href:"fff.html",
    onClosed: overrideFunction
});

function overrideFunction() {
  /your overriding function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there might be cleaner solutions, what you could do is

```
// in the window scope! Can be explicitely set with
// window.onColorboxClose without var before it.
var onColorboxClose = function(){
};

$.colorbox({
  href:"fff.html",
  onClosed:onColorboxClose 
});
```

and then overwrite the function afterwards rather than passing it as a closure to the properties of the colorbox.

Answer (score 1):

Another work around was to override the close event to get a complete control of close event handling

```
    var c_close = $.fn.colorbox.close;
    // Now disable the close function
    $.fn.colorbox.close = function(){

        if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
            c_close();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```